# How can I remove many files with names that are encapsulated in single quotes?

Tags: linux, rm

I have a log directory with thousands of files that are named similar to this:

```
''$'\351\243\216\346\211\207\343\200\201\347\273\204\345\220\210'' strutstore A'$'\350\241\250''.xlsx'
```

I want to delete any file that has a single quote in its name. I can't figure out how to match them. When I try:

```
ls ''*
```

I get:

```
ls: unrecognized option '----------------z-2020-02-12 ZTL-Y-.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to pass filename arguments that begin with a hyphen, you should use a [double hyphen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/20805) to terminate your own command options, for example:

```
ls -- ''*
```